# Android: what should I use for android push notification? Google Cloud Messaging or Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android project. Can anyone give me an idea what should I use for notification ? Using GCM it seems to be hard to implement where as using parse.com its seems easier. But is it recommended to use parse.com for notification?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Parse.com uses GCM so I would go with that option. Implementing GCM on your own requires you to have a server mitigating and keeping track of id's which parse.com does for you with their installation objects.

Answer (score 0):

Nil, you have not mentioned two things. Is your app communicates with cloud/Server? And what is the backend your using, parse.com or something else(PHP,Java,.Net)?

Well, if you're using Parse.com as your backend support, i would recommend to use Parse push notifications. Parse uses GCM for Android push notifications.

If your backend is some other server, i will opt for GCM as you don't need to maintain data again on the parse. If you have different backend and want to use parse, app should communicate with the two servers one for actual communication and other for storing your device ID into parse.

Comment: Ya I am using php web server in back end. Can I send data for notification to parse from the webserver as we can in GCM?

Comment: @Nil To do so, you have to maintain two databases one at parse.com and other at your actual database(PHP) which is not a good design. There is a rest api call to send the push notification from PHP. What you need to do is to associate the device token with user into your DB and send it to GCM.

I don't say we cannot achieve the same with Parse but it is hard to maintain data at two places.